# Lotus Notes MIME Conversion - Content returns null

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

I am trying to access Lotus Notes NSF Files to convert them to EML, so far it is working fine but it fails randomly for some files.

I am creating a Notes Session without MIME conversion:

```
NotesSession session = new NotesSession();
session.Initialize(GLNAdminPassword);
session.ConvertMime = false;
NotesDatabase db = session.GetDatabase(GLNServer, GLNFilePath, true);
```

==========

```
if (doc.GetFirstItem("Body") != null)
bool result = WriteMIMEOutput(doc.NoteID + ".eml", doc.NoteID, db, session);
```

The Write MIME output creates MIME as following:

```
private static bool WriteMIMEOutput(string outfile, string noteid, NotesDatabase nsf,

                       NotesSession session)
{
    try
    {
        Domino.NotesMIMEEntity mE = null;
        Domino.NotesMIMEEntity mChild = null;
        bool result = false;
        string contentType = null;
        string headers = null;
        string content = null;
        string preamble = null;
        MIME_ENCODING encoding;
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outfile);
        NotesDocument doc = nsf.GetDocumentByID(noteid);

        if (doc == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("doc = null");

            goto XEnd;
        }


        mE = doc.GetMIMEEntity("body");

        if (mE == null)
        {
            SQLMIMEErrorlogger(ex, noteid);

            goto XEnd;
        }

        contentType = mE.ContentType;
        headers = mE.Headers;
        encoding = mE.Encoding;

        // message envelope. If no MIME-Version header, add one
        if (!headers.Contains("MIME-Version:"))
            writer.WriteLine("MIME-Version: 1.0");
        writer.WriteLine(headers);

        // for multipart, usually no main-msg content...
        if (content != null && content.Trim().Length > 0)
            writer.WriteLine(content);
        writer.Flush();

        if (contentType.StartsWith("multipart"))
        {
            preamble = mE.Preamble;
            mChild = mE.GetFirstChildEntity();
            while (mChild != null)
            {
                headers = mChild.Headers;
                encoding = mChild.Encoding;

                // if it's a binary part, force it to b64
                if (encoding == MIME_ENCODING.ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY)
                {
                    mChild.EncodeContent(MIME_ENCODING.ENC_BASE64);
                    headers = mChild.Headers;
                }

                preamble = mChild.Preamble;

                content = mChild.BoundaryStart;
                writer.Write(content);
                if (!content.EndsWith("\n"))
                    writer.WriteLine("");

                writer.WriteLine(headers);
                writer.WriteLine();

                content = mChild.ContentAsText;
                writer.Write(content);
                writer.Write(mChild.BoundaryEnd);
                writer.Flush();
                mChild = mChild.GetNextSibling();
            } // end while
        } // end multipart
        if (contentType.StartsWith("text/plain"))
        {
            preamble = mE.Preamble;
            mChild = mE.GetFirstChildEntity();
            while (mChild != null)
            {
                headers = mChild.Headers;
                encoding = mChild.Encoding;

                // if it's a binary part, force it to b64
                if (encoding == MIME_ENCODING.ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY)
                {
                    mChild.EncodeContent(MIME_ENCODING.ENC_BASE64);
                    headers = mChild.Headers;
                }

                preamble = mChild.Preamble;

                content = mChild.BoundaryStart;
                writer.Write(content);
                if (!content.EndsWith("\n"))
                    writer.WriteLine("");

                writer.WriteLine(headers);
                writer.WriteLine();

                content = mChild.ContentAsText;
                writer.Write(content);
                writer.Write(mChild.BoundaryEnd);
                writer.Flush();
                mChild = mChild.GetNextSibling();
            } // end while
        } //
        if (contentType.StartsWith("text/html"))
        {
            preamble = mE.Preamble;
            mChild = mE.GetFirstChildEntity();
            while (mChild != null)
            {
                headers = mChild.Headers;
                encoding = mChild.Encoding;

                // if it's a binary part, force it to b64
                if (encoding == MIME_ENCODING.ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY)
                {
                    mChild.EncodeContent(MIME_ENCODING.ENC_BASE64);
                    headers = mChild.Headers;
                }

                preamble = mChild.Preamble;

                content = mChild.BoundaryStart;
                writer.Write(content);
                if (!content.EndsWith("\n"))
                    writer.WriteLine("");

                writer.WriteLine(headers);
                writer.WriteLine();

                content = mChild.ContentAsText;
                writer.Write(content);
                writer.Write(mChild.BoundaryEnd);
                writer.Flush();
                mChild = mChild.GetNextSibling();
            } // end while
        } //
        // end of main envelope
        writer.WriteLine(mE.BoundaryEnd);
        result = true;

    XEnd:

        if (writer != null)
            writer.Close();
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SQLMIMEErrorlogger(ex, noteid);

        return false;
    }
}
```

But
`content = mChild.ContentAsText;` 
randomly returns empty text which creates emails with no body, what could be the reason of this.

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt it's random; it's probably specific messages. I don't see any provision in your code for detecting which messages aren't being handled. A final 'else' clause in your logic would be a good first start. In fact, you really ought to be using 'else if' constructs instead of just a sequence of 'if' statements that assume they are both mutually exclusive and exhaustive. Once you've determined which emails are problematic, an examination of the properties of the body and its component MIME parts (if there are any, which won't be the case for native rich text) will lead you to your answer.

Comment: Hi Richard, Thanks a lot, after a lot of messing around I found that I need to loop properly through child/parent/sibling documents and check if the mime is multipart or text.